# Open source alternative to ISA/Forefront TMG?

Tags: isa-server, single-sign-on, microsoft-forefront

I'm using Forefront TMG to do web server publishing & SSO and very little else.  Are there any open source alternatives that can satisfy all (or at least most) of these features:

- Web server publishing
- Load balancing
- URL (re)mapping
- Web based single sign on w/ support for http basic/ntlm/kerberos authentication on the backend web server
- Ability to add hooks into the login process or even develop your own

Customizing the forms based authentication pages on Forefront is a nightmare of terrible javascript, html, and css.  It also doesn't provide a way to hook into the login process.  Ideally I'd like to drop it and use something more extensible/free.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like Apache httpd should be able to do all those things using:

- http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html
- http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy_balancer.html
- http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html
- http://modauthkerb.sourceforge.net/
- ...

This is of course not an out-of-the-box solution, but with some googling it shouldn't be to hard to figure out + it's very customizable

btw. the next Forefront TMG version should be much better... ;)

Comment: the next TMG better be. We waited so long with our aging 2003 ISA and when we moved to TMG and found out it was almost identical.

Comment: Thanks, this looks promising.  Looks like apache is adding forms based authentication too: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/mod/mod_auth_form.html

Comment: "the next Forefront TMG version should be much better" - that's a good joke, now that Microsoft announced the death of TMG: http://blogs.technet.com/b/server-cloud/archive/2012/09/12/important-changes-to-forefront-product-roadmaps.aspx